# Improve CASE select performance on view creation

Tags: sql-server, performance, case

I am new to SQL, and the below view query is taking a long time to return values because of the case statement, can someone help in identifying how I can speed things up?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "ARBANCDB"."V_GDW_REPLICA" 
          ("WWID", 
           "LAST_NAME", 
           "FIRST_NAME", 
           "MIDDLE_NAME", 
           "FULL_NAME", 
           "SUFFIX_NAME", 
           "CONTINUOUS_SERVICE_DATE", 
           "COST_CENTER_CODE", 
           "COST_CENTER_DESC", 
           "EMPLOYMENT_STATUS", 
           "EMPLOYMENT_STATUS_CODE", 
           "FLSA_CODE", 
           "FTE_PCT", 
           "JOB_FUNCTION_CODE", 
           "JOB_SUBFUNCTION_CODE", 
           "HIRE_DATE", 
           "JOB_FUNCTION", 
           "JOB_GROUP", 
           "JOB_HIERARCHY", 
           "JOB_HIER_CD", 
           "JOB_ID", 
           "JOB_SUBFUNCTION", 
           "LATEST_JOB_EFFECTIVE_DATE", 
           "LEGAL_ENTITY", 
           "LEGAL_ENTITY_CODE", 
           "MANAGER_FIRST_NAME", 
           "MANAGER_FULL_NAME", 
           "MANAGER_LAST_NAME", 
           "MANAGER_POSITION_TITLE", 
           "MANAGER_SUPERVISORY_ORG", 
           "MANAGER_WWID", 
           "MRC", 
           "MRC_CODE", 
           "ORIGINAL_HIRE_DATE", 
           "PAY_FREQUENCY_CODE", 
           "PAY_RATE_TYPE", 
           "POSITION_TITLE", 
           "REPORTING_HIERARCHY", 
           "LEVEL01", 
           "LEVEL02", 
           "LEVEL03", 
           "LEVEL04", 
           "LEVEL05", 
           "LEVEL06", 
           "LEVEL07", 
           "LEVEL08", 
           "LEVEL09", 
           "LEVEL10", 
           "LEVEL11", 
           "LEVEL12", 
           "LEVEL13", 
           "LEVEL14", 
           "LEVEL15", 
           "LEVEL16", 
           "LEVEL17", 
           "LNAME01", 
           "LNAME02", 
           "LNAME03", 
           "LNAME04", 
           "LNAME05", 
           "LNAME06", 
           "LNAME07", 
           "LNAME08", 
           "LNAME09", 
           "LNAME10", 
           "LNAME11", 
           "LNAME12", 
           "LNAME13", 
           "LNAME14", 
           "LNAME15", 
           "LNAME16", 
           "LNAME17", 
           "SALES_INCENTIVE_IND", 
           "SCHEDULED_WEEKLY_HOURS", 
           "SECTOR", 
           "SECTOR_CODE", 
           "SUPERVISORY_ORG", 
           "TERMINATION_DATE", 
           "TIME_TYPE", 
           "WORK_ADDRESS_1", 
           "WORK_ADDRESS_2", 
           "WORK_ADDRESS_3", 
           "WORK_ADDRESS_4", 
           "WORK_CITY", 
           "WORK_COUNTRY", 
           "WORK_COUNTRY_CODE", 
           "WORK_EMAIL", 
           "WORK_POSTAL_CODE", 
           "WORK_REGION", 
           "WORK_STATE_CODE", 
           "WORKER_SUBTYPE", 
           "WORKER_TYPE", 
           "REGION_CODE", 
           "REGION_NAME", 
           "MOBILE_PHONE", 
           "BUSINESS_PHONE", 
           "USER_NAME", 
           "DOMAIN_NAME", 
           "WINDOWS_UPN", 
           "ACQUISITION_CODE", 
           "ACQUISITION_DATE", 
           "DEFAULT_WEEKLY_HOURS", 
           "HR_SOURCE_SYSTEM", 
           "HR_SOURCE_SYSTEM_CODE", 
           "CAMPUS_CODE", 
           "MGR_EMAIL_ADDR", 
           "WORK_STATE_CODE_2", 
           "FIN_CC_CD", 
           "BUS_AREA_CD", 
           "LAST_UPDATE_DATE", 
           "NUMBER_DIRECTREPORTS", 
           "BUSN_UN_CD", 
           "SITE", 
           "JOB_HIER_ID_LVL", 
           "JOB_HIER_NAME_LVL", 
           "ACTV_DIRY_EMAIL_ADDR", 
           "ACTV_DIRY_USRNM", 
           "ROW_ADD_TMS", 
           "ROW_ADD_PGM_NO", 
           "ROW_UPDT_TMS", 
           "ROW_UPDT_PGM_NO") AS 
  SELECT A.wwid, A.last_name, 
         A.first_name, 
         A.middle_name, 
         A.full_name,       
         A.suffix_name, 
         A.continuous_service_date, 
         A.cost_center_code,       
         A.cost_center_desc, 
         A.employment_status,       
         A.employment_status_code, 
         A.flsa_code, A.fte_pct,       
         A.job_function_code, 
         A.job_subfunction_code, 
         A.hire_date,       
         A.job_function, 
         A.job_group, 
         A.job_hierarchy, 
         A.job_hier_cd,       
         A.job_id, 
         A.job_subfunction, 
         A.latest_job_effective_date,       
         A.legal_entity, 
         A.legal_entity_code,
        (CASE 
         WHEN A.IA_TYPE IS NULL THEN A.MANAGER_FIRST_NAME
         ELSE (SELECT B.FIRST_NAME FROM arbancdb.gdw_replica B WHERE B.wwid=A.HOST_MANAGER_WWID)END) AS MANAGER_FIRST_NAME,
        (CASE 
         WHEN A.IA_TYPE IS NULL THEN A.MANAGER_FULL_NAME
         ELSE (SELECT B.FULL_NAME FROM arbancdb.gdw_replica B WHERE B.wwid=A.HOST_MANAGER_WWID)END) AS MANAGER_FULL_NAME,
        (CASE 
         WHEN A.IA_TYPE IS NULL THEN A.MANAGER_LAST_NAME
         ELSE (SELECT B.LAST_NAME FROM arbancdb.gdw_replica B WHERE B.wwid=A.HOST_MANAGER_WWID)END) AS MANAGER_LAST_NAME,    
        (CASE 
         WHEN A.IA_TYPE IS NULL THEN A.manager_position_title
         ELSE (SELECT B.position_title FROM arbancdb.gdw_replica B WHERE B.wwid=A.HOST_MANAGER_WWID)END) AS manager_position_title,
        (CASE 
         WHEN A.IA_TYPE IS NULL THEN A.manager_supervisory_org
         ELSE (SELECT B.supervisory_org FROM arbancdb.gdw_replica B WHERE B.wwid=A.HOST_MANAGER_WWID)END) AS manager_supervisory_org,
        (CASE 
         WHEN A.IA_TYPE IS NULL THEN A.MANAGER_WWID
         ELSE HOST_MANAGER_WWID END) AS MANAGER_WWID,
        A.mrc, 
        A.mrc_code, 
        A.original_hire_date,       
        A.pay_frequency_code, 
        A.pay_rate_type, 
        A.position_title,       
        A.reporting_hierarchy, 
        A.level01, 
        A.level02, 
        A.level03,       
        A.level04, 
        A.level05, 
        A.level06, 
        A.level07, 
        A.level08, 
        A.level09,       
        A.level10, 
        A.level11, 
        A.level12, 
        A.level13, 
        A.level14, 
        A.level15,       
        A.level16, 
        A.level17, 
        A.lname01, 
        A.lname02, 
        A.lname03, 
        A.lname04,       
        A.lname05, 
        A.lname06, 
        A.lname07, 
        A.lname08, 
        A.lname09, 
        A.lname10,       
        A.lname11, 
        A.lname12, 
        A.lname13, 
        A.lname14, 
        A.lname15, 
        A.lname16,       
        A.lname17, 
        A.sales_incentive_ind, 
        A.scheduled_weekly_hours,       
        A.sector, 
        A.sector_code, 
        A.supervisory_org, 
        A.termination_date,       
        A.time_type, 
        A.work_address_1, 
        A.work_address_2,       
        A.work_address_3, 
        A.work_address_4, 
        A.work_city, 
        A.work_country,       
        A.work_country_code, 
        (CASE 
         WHEN A.work_email IS NULL THEN A.actv_diry_email_addr 
         ELSE A.work_email END) AS work_email, 
        A.work_postal_code,      
        A.work_region, 
        A.work_state_code, 
        A.worker_subtype,       
        A.worker_type, 
        A.region_code, 
        A.region_name, 
        A.mobile_phone,       
        A.business_phone, 
        A.USER_NAME, 
        A.domain_name, 
        A.windows_upn,       
        A.acquisition_code, 
        A.acquisition_date, 
        A.default_weekly_hours,       
        A.hr_source_system, 
        A.hr_source_system_code, 
        A.campus_code,       
        A.mgr_email_addr, 
        A.work_state_code_2, 
        A.fin_cc_cd,       
        A.bus_area_cd, 
        A.last_update_date, 
        A.number_directreports, 
        (SELECT B.BUSN_UN_CD FROM sapncdb.V_LYNX_COST_CTR_STGEG@sapncdb B WHERE lpad(cost_ctr_cd,10,'0') =A.fin_cc_cd )AS BUSN_UN_CD, 
        (SELECT C.default_site FROM sapncdb.V_LYNX_COST_CTR_STGEG@sapncdb B, arbancdb.BU C WHERE lpad(cost_ctr_cd,10,'0') =A.fin_cc_cd AND B.BUSN_UN_CD = C.bu_cd) AS SITE,
        A.job_hier_id_lvl,
        A.job_hier_name_lvl,
        A.actv_diry_email_addr,
        A.actv_diry_usrnm, 
        A.row_add_tms, 
        A.row_add_pgm_no, 
        A.row_updt_tms,      
        A.row_updt_pgm_no  
   FROM arbancdb.gdw_replica A;
```

Comment: Could you please post the query plan at https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ It would be much easier for others to explain/answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try joining to `arbancdb.gdw_replica` in your  `FROM` clause (use a `LEFT JOIN` to avoid filtering. That way you’ll have access to those columns you use in your CASE statements.

Answer (score -2):

I have attempted to make it a bit faster by using below script:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "ARBANCDB"."V_GDW_REPLICA" ("WWID", "LAST_NAME", "FIRST_NAME", "MIDDLE_NAME", "FULL_NAME", "SUFFIX_NAME", "CONTINUOUS_SERVICE_DATE", "COST_CENTER_CODE", "COST_CENTER_DESC", "EMPLOYMENT_STATUS", "EMPLOYMENT_STATUS_CODE", "FLSA_CODE", "FTE_PCT", "JOB_FUNCTION_CODE", "JOB_SUBFUNCTION_CODE", "HIRE_DATE", "JOB_FUNCTION", "JOB_GROUP", "JOB_HIERARCHY", "JOB_HIER_CD", "JOB_ID", "JOB_SUBFUNCTION", "LATEST_JOB_EFFECTIVE_DATE", "LEGAL_ENTITY", "LEGAL_ENTITY_CODE", "MANAGER_FIRST_NAME", "MANAGER_FULL_NAME", "MANAGER_LAST_NAME", "MANAGER_POSITION_TITLE", "MANAGER_SUPERVISORY_ORG", "MANAGER_WWID", "MRC", "MRC_CODE", "ORIGINAL_HIRE_DATE", "PAY_FREQUENCY_CODE", "PAY_RATE_TYPE", "POSITION_TITLE", "REPORTING_HIERARCHY", "LEVEL01", "LEVEL02", "LEVEL03", "LEVEL04", "LEVEL05", "LEVEL06", "LEVEL07", "LEVEL08", "LEVEL09", "LEVEL10", "LEVEL11", "LEVEL12", "LEVEL13", "LEVEL14", "LEVEL15", "LEVEL16", "LEVEL17", "LNAME01", "LNAME02", "LNAME03", "LNAME04", "LNAME05", "LNAME06", "LNAME07", "LNAME08", "LNAME09", "LNAME10", "LNAME11", "LNAME12", "LNAME13", "LNAME14", "LNAME15", "LNAME16", "LNAME17", "SALES_INCENTIVE_IND", "SCHEDULED_WEEKLY_HOURS", "SECTOR", "SECTOR_CODE", "SUPERVISORY_ORG", "TERMINATION_DATE", "TIME_TYPE", "WORK_ADDRESS_1", "WORK_ADDRESS_2", "WORK_ADDRESS_3", "WORK_ADDRESS_4", "WORK_CITY", "WORK_COUNTRY", "WORK_COUNTRY_CODE", "WORK_EMAIL", "WORK_POSTAL_CODE", "WORK_REGION", "WORK_STATE_CODE", "WORKER_SUBTYPE", "WORKER_TYPE", "REGION_CODE", "REGION_NAME", "MOBILE_PHONE", "BUSINESS_PHONE", "USER_NAME", "DOMAIN_NAME", "WINDOWS_UPN", "ACQUISITION_CODE", "ACQUISITION_DATE", "DEFAULT_WEEKLY_HOURS", "HR_SOURCE_SYSTEM", "HR_SOURCE_SYSTEM_CODE", "CAMPUS_CODE", "MGR_EMAIL_ADDR", "WORK_STATE_CODE_2", "FIN_CC_CD", "BUS_AREA_CD", "LAST_UPDATE_DATE", "NUMBER_DIRECTREPORTS", "BUSN_UN_CD", "SITE", "JOB_HIER_ID_LVL", "JOB_HIER_NAME_LVL", "ACTV_DIRY_EMAIL_ADDR", "ACTV_DIRY_USRNM", "ROW_ADD_TMS", "ROW_ADD_PGM_NO", "ROW_UPDT_TMS", "ROW_UPDT_PGM_NO") AS 
      SELECT a.wwid, a.last_name, a.first_name, a.middle_name, a.full_name,       a.suffix_name, a.continuous_service_date, a.cost_center_code,       a.cost_center_desc, a.employment_status,       a.employment_status_code, a.flsa_code, a.fte_pct,       a.job_function_code, a.job_subfunction_code, a.hire_date,       a.job_function, a.job_group, a.job_hierarchy, a.job_hier_cd,       a.job_id, a.job_subfunction, a.latest_job_effective_date,       a.legal_entity, a.legal_entity_code,
      (CASE 
        WHEN    a.IA_TYPE is null 
            THEN a.MANAGER_FIRST_NAME
        ELSE b.FIRST_NAME END) as MANAGER_FIRST_NAME,
      (CASE 
        WHEN    a.IA_TYPE is null   
            THEN a.MANAGER_FULL_NAME
        ELSE b.FULL_NAME END) as MANAGER_FULL_NAME,
     (CASE 
        WHEN    a.IA_TYPE is null 
            THEN a.MANAGER_LAST_NAME
        ELSE b.LAST_NAME END) as MANAGER_LAST_NAME, 
         (CASE 
        WHEN    a.IA_TYPE is null 
            THEN a.manager_position_title
        ELSE b.position_title END) as manager_position_title,
         (CASE 
        WHEN    a.IA_TYPE is null 
            THEN a.manager_supervisory_org
        ELSE b.supervisory_org END) as manager_supervisory_org,
       (CASE 
        WHEN    a.IA_TYPE is null 
            THEN a.MANAGER_WWID
        ELSE a.HOST_MANAGER_WWID END) as MANAGER_WWID,
      a.mrc, a.mrc_code, a.original_hire_date,       a.pay_frequency_code, a.pay_rate_type, a.position_title,       a.reporting_hierarchy, a.level01, a.level02, a.level03,       a.level04, a.level05, a.level06, a.level07, a.level08, a.level09,       a.level10, a.level11, a.level12, a.level13, a.level14, a.level15,       a.level16, a.level17, a.lname01, a.lname02, a.lname03, a.lname04,       a.lname05, a.lname06, a.lname07, a.lname08, a.lname09, a.lname10,       a.lname11, a.lname12, a.lname13, a.lname14, a.lname15, a.lname16,       a.lname17, a.sales_incentive_ind, a.scheduled_weekly_hours,       a.sector, a.sector_code, a.supervisory_org, a.termination_date,       a.time_type, a.work_address_1, a.work_address_2,       a.work_address_3, a.work_address_4, a.work_city, a.work_country,       a.work_country_code, (CASE WHEN a.work_email is null THEN a.actv_diry_email_addr ELSE a.work_email END) as work_email, a.work_postal_code,       a.work_region, a.work_state_code, a.worker_subtype,       a.worker_type, a.region_code, a.region_name, a.mobile_phone,       a.business_phone, a.user_name, a.domain_name, a.windows_upn,       a.acquisition_code, a.acquisition_date, a.default_weekly_hours,       a.hr_source_system, a.hr_source_system_code, a.campus_code,       a.mgr_email_addr, a.work_state_code_2, a.fin_cc_cd,       a.bus_area_cd, a.last_update_date, a.number_directreports, (select b.BUSN_UN_CD from sapncdb.V_LYNX_COST_CTR_STGEG@sapncdb b where lpad(cost_ctr_cd,10,'0') =a.fin_cc_cd )as BUSN_UN_CD, (select c.default_site from sapncdb.V_LYNX_COST_CTR_STGEG@sapncdb b, arbancdb.BU c where lpad(cost_ctr_cd,10,'0') =a.fin_cc_cd and b.BUSN_UN_CD = c.bu_cd) as site,a.job_hier_id_lvl,a.job_hier_name_lvl,a.actv_diry_email_addr,a.actv_diry_usrnm, a.row_add_tms, a.row_add_pgm_no, a.row_updt_tms,       a.row_updt_pgm_no  FROM arbancdb.gdw_replica a left outer join arbancdb.gdw_replica b on a.HOST_MANAGER_WWID=b.wwid;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome to **Database Administrators**. Please, check [How do I write a good answer?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) to better contribute with your knowledge.